# How to display number of pageviews on articles and pages

Tags: 7

I am looking to display the number of pageviews for articles and pages next to where it has tags for example.

Are there any modules that do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with [Node view count](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeviewcount) module ?

> Node View Count module allows to count node views. Unlike statistics module, this module records each view of node with user uid and timestamp. So now you can know how many times a user viewed node by day, week, month and etc.

Comment: ya sort of but it doesn't show the view count next to the articles, any idea on how to do that?

Comment: These module supports views, try creating block with node count & use contextual filter as node id...  try